# How to print a xml attribut value in the console using Logstash

Tags: java, xml, logstash, logstash-configuration

Here is the xml file, i want to print the name attribute value "testSuite.DriverScript" in the console.

Comment: Where is xml file???

Comment: you should show your xml and what you have coded yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="1" verbose="1" name="SampleSuite-Linear" annotations="JDK" parallel="classes">
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name="utilities.reporting.ReportNGScreenshot" />
  </listeners>
  <test name="RunTests">
    <classes>
      <class name="testSuite.DriverScript" /> </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my conf file

```
input {    file    {    path=>["C:/logstash-2.1.1/Data/TestNG_Linear.xml"]    start_position =>"beginning"    type =>suitefile   }    }    filter    {    xml    {    source => "message"    #store_xml => false    add_tag => "xml"    xpath => ["//*/class/*/@name","name"]    }    }    output    {    stdout {codec => rubydebug}    }
```